# How to compare a String to Date in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables table1 with column tran_date datatype datetime and table2 with column tran_date datatype varchar(50).

in table2 the tran_date has values like 1/1/2000.

now how to compare these 2 columns?

I tried the following:

```
select * 
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where CAST(t1.tran_date AS DATETIME) = CAST(t2.tran_date AS DATETIME)
```

Regards:

Comment: What result you got after trying?

Comment: there were no rows selected, means the comparison did not work. the query by Itay Grudev worked, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL simply has a function called [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) which coverts a string into a Date which you can then use to compare it with another date.

Here is an example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(t2.tran_date, '%m/%d/%Y') = t1.tran_date
```

*Note* that it requires the date format to be specified (second argument). Check the [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) reference for details.

Hope it helps.

Comment: And the exact format is explicitly specified in the question

Comment: thanks this worked: SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(t2.tran_date, '%m/%d/%Y') = t1.tran_date

Answer (score 0):

Use **[STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)**

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(t1.tran_date, '%m/%d/%Y') = STR_TO_DATE(t2.tran_date, '%m/%d/%Y')
```